# MongoDB replica set write with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I use mongodb native driver for node.js to connect to replica set of 3 nodes(PRIMARY and two SECONDARIES) as described here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/MongoClient.html

```
 var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;     

 var url = "mongodb://admin:pass@hostname:27017";
 var options = {
  db: {
    readPreference: 'primaryPreferred',
    slaveOk: true
  },
  replSet: {
    replicaSet: 'rs0'
  },
  server: {
    w: 1,
    autoReconnect: true
  };

 MongoClient.connect(url, options);
```

Note that `slaveOk: true` is not documented, without it I keep getting slaveOk is false error.
I keep getting `Potentially unhandled rejection [83] MongoError: not master` on writes.
Can you please help to connect to a replica set from node application? Maybe I shall specify all the servers for the connection? But it's said in docs that driver is smart enough to reconnect when PRIMARY changes.

Answer (score 2):

In order to allow the client to switch between replica-set members as needed, you need to tell it that these alternative replica-set members exist. To do this, provide the URLs of all the replica-set members separated by comma.

```
var url = "mongodb://admin:pass@hostname1:27017,mongodb://admin:pass@hostname2:27017,mongodb://admin:pass@hostname3:27017,";
```

When you want to abstract the replica-set configuration from the application to have more flexibility, you can build a sharded cluster and have the application connect to the router. The router will then take care of forwarding the connection to an appropriate replica-set member

Comment: Thank you Philipp, it worked with string like this:
`mongodb://admin:pass@host_one:27017,host_two:27017,host_three:27017/dbName`
Can you please edit your answer
Mongo docs definitely miss some examples :(

Comment: @Philip Thats strange. For all other drivers I am aware of it should be sufficient to denote that we are connecting to a replica set using the appropriate option (`replSet=replSetName`) in the connection string and the driver will discover the other replicaSet members. The drivers assume implicitly that you are connecting to a replica set in case more than on URL is given, iirc.